# Whats the difference between `any` and `var` in ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I am trying to do

```
var myVar = "my var";

match myVar {
    string s => { io:println("string"); }
    any k => { io:println("any var"); }
}
```

seems that's not correct. Whats the difference between `var` and `any`. I think when I use `var` underneath ballerina creates an `any` ? correct?

Comment: Think I found the answer to my question.

Answer (score 5):

"any" is the type which denotes all the values that a Ballerina program can operate on.

```
any myVal = "this is a string value";

// Unsafe type cast, hence the union type.
string | error myStr = <string> myVal; 

// Following is also valid based on the definition of the "any" type. 
any myVal = 10;
```

"var" is a way of declaring a variable whose type is inferred from right-hand side expression. Once the type of the variable is derived, you can only assign values of that type.

```
// This is equivalent to 'string a = "this is a string value";'
var a = "this is a string value"; 

// Now the following will result in a compilation failure. 
a = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the answer to my question.

"The "var" type, the type is inferred from the right hand side, determined by looking at the static type of the right hand side.
Whereas the "any" type represents all types collectively together."

My bad of not reading the docs :(